# MySql query con join

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo 3 tablas: clientes, vehiculo, inmueble.

Están asi de datos:

```
clientes: cedula 
vehiculo: cedula, placa
inmueble: cedula matricula
```

Una misma cedula puede tener varias casas y vehiculos o ninguno.

Cuando genero mi consulta que es esta:

```
SELECT clientes.cedula, inmuebles.N_Matricula, vehiculos.Placa
FROM clientes  
INNER JOIN vehiculos 
ON (clientes.cedula=vehiculos.cedula)
INNER JOIN inmuebles  
ON (clientes.cedula=inmuebles.cedula)
WHERE clientes.cedula = 15047046
```

Me trae 12 registros repitiendo 3 veces la matricula y 4 la placa..
lo que necesito es que se empaten y salga algo asi

```
cedula matricula 1  placa 1 /n.....................
cedula matricula 2  placa 2 /n.....................
cedula matricula 3  placa 3 /n.....................
cedula matricula 4  null /n
```

y asi si es al contrario dado el caso que existan mas placas que matriculas

Comment: Creo que no es del todo clara la forma en la que quieres que se empaten los datos de matrícula y placa (porque no estableces ninguna relación pero en la salida de ejemplo reusas una misma cédula con valores diferentes sin decirnos de qué va la matrícula1 con la placa1). Si usas datos de prueba como ejemplo, seguro nos es más fácil ayudar.

Comment: parceros las tablas no tienen ninguna relacion, solo la cedula del propietario.